# 2017 Nissan Sentra engine cranks but won't start

Tags: nissan, cranks-wont-run, sentra

It has spark it has fuel it has compression but won't start and there's black soot on the ground behind my tailpipe.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You said it has spark/fuel/compression ... how did you verify these?